# Can't review an edit on a specific post after "You have failed too many recent review audits"

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, review-audits

I recently got the

> You have failed too many recent review audits – looks like you might
>   need a break.

after failing an audit. I am unable during the temporary ban to review from the [review queues](https://stackoverflow.com/review/), but I also receive the same message when clicking the `edit (1)` link on a post when it shows up. The dialog box shows the same message as the review page. Why is this, and should it be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`edit (1)` means there’s a pending suggested edit on the post that needs to be approved or declined. Since you can’t review suggested edits, you can’t edit until it’s cleared.

I’m pretty sure that’s working as intended.

Comment: I don't believe robo-reviewers are willing to go to individual posts to review edits. The temporary ban does not affect the casting of votes, including close votes.

Comment: @Mooseman: People can be banned for other reasons. I’d personally rather this weren’t changed.

Comment: So [are you a robo-reviewer](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2672834), @Mooseman, or did something else go wrong here?

Comment: @CodyGray This obviously should be rejected based on the added text, which is vandalism.

Comment: @Mooseman: “So why did you approve it?” is what’s being asked, I think.

Comment: @minitechη There are errors: accidental clicks, etc. Which is another reason I see why 5 users must approve an edit or cast a close vote for action to be taken.

Comment: @Mooseman Then slow down when you're reviewing, so you don't misclick